# Heroku Application error ( nodemon: not found )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, nodemon

My application runs well locally but when I use the command 'git push heroku', it got an application error. The I use the command 'heroku logs --tail' and it shows the error info as below. I hope someone can help me with this issue, many thanks.

// From my terminal:

```
2022-07-27T15:44:24.983651+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon --watch 
backend --exec babel-node backend/server.js
2022-07-27T15:44:24.983654+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-27T15:44:25.031291+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: 
not found
2022-07-27T15:44:25.310188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited 
with status 127
2022-07-27T15:44:25.401566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed 
from starting to crashed
2022-07-27T15:44:47.638568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error 
code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-amason- 
app.herokuapp.com request_id=c61d813e-1467-4474-8b4d- 
ad2ecc4141ad fwd="162.212.108.4" dyno= connect= service= 
status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-27T15:44:47.962345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error 
code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=my-amason-app.herokuapp.com request_id=243e98ef-4b26-4a93- 
89f5-38515d30a4a4 fwd="162.212.108.4" dyno= connect= service= 
status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-27T16:09:50.250878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error 
code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-amason- 
app.herokuapp.com request_id=56e35e15-10e9-4609-8af0- 
9d42d97bdde7 fwd="162.212.108.4" dyno= connect= service= 
status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-27T16:09:50.746665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error 
code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=my-amason-app.herokuapp.com request_id=dfe6b501-c155-4e8a- 
8e8d-ad115771fd08 fwd="162.212.108.4" dyno= connect= service= 
status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

//package.json:

```
{
 "dependencies": {
 "@babel/cli": "^7.18.6",
 "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
 "@babel/node": "^7.18.6",
 "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
 "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
 "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
 "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
 "express": "^4.18.1",
 "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
 "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
 "mongoose": "^5.13.14",
 "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
 "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.3",
 "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
 },
"name": "amason",
"version": "1.0.0",
"type": "module",
"main": "index.js",
"devDependencies": {
"nodemon": "^2.0.18"
},
"engines": {
"node": "16.13.2",
"npm": "8.1.2"
 },
"scripts": {
"build": "cd frontend && npm install && npm run build",
"start": "nodemon --watch backend --exec babel-node 
          backend/server.js"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "description": ""
 }
```

// Procfile:

```
web:node --experimental-modules backend/server.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For development use nodemon. Example  => "start":"nodemon index.js"

> For production use node. Example  => "start":"node index.js".

Comment: I changed "start": "nodemon --watch backend --exec babel-node backend/server.js" to ' "start": "node index.js", but it got another error as:

2022-07-27T17:14:43.445937+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2022-07-27T17:14:43.445940+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2022-07-27T17:14:43.445941+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-07-27T17:14:43.445941+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: []

Comment: you've fixed one. another one appeared. no one can fix it if you don't share the resource. please upload the project on Github then share it with me. I'll try to debug. thank you

Comment: just changed to "start": "node backend/server.js", then it works! Thanks so much for your suggestion!

Comment: my pleasure. good luck